# Is there a difference between calling fit in a loop vs fit with batch size

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

Let's say, I have 32 training example in memory (batch size will be 32). Is there a difference between calling `fit` in a for loop for 32 times with `batch_size=1` for examples one by one; or getting all experiences together in an array and calling `fit` once but with `batch_size=32` as the parameter? Will there be any difference in results or performance?

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(32):
    model.fit(X,y,batch_size=1)
```

Don't train your model this way.! Your effectively training only on your last batch (In your case last sample)

But, the below method will assure you that the model is trained on all the samples. So always train it this way.

```
model.fit(X,y,batch_size=32)
```

If you thought about using "for loop" because you couldn't fit all the sample's into memory at once, You should try fit_generator or fit_on_batch methods.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, yes batch size affects the speed and convergence - because the updates happen after each batch.

However, for a total training size of 32, it may not matter much

Comment: No, total training size will not be 32 of course, it was just an example. Which will be faster and convergence better? It seems I should change learning rate to make a better comparasion between these two, is it true?

Comment: There is no correct answer, increasing batch size makes each epochs faster - but may have impact on convergence.  You need to try it out.  It is like an art. https://towardsdatascience.com/what-are-hyperparameters-and-how-to-tune-the-hyperparameters-in-a-deep-neural-network-d0604917584a